# static inline functions in a header file

Tags: c

Lately I have been making an attempt to read more open source C code. A common pattern that I have been adopting in my hobby projects is as follows.

In my C files, I have functions that are either static or exported. Only functions that are exported are placed in a header file. Global variables which are only used within the scope of an object are also used as static global variables.

My question concerns the usefulness and motivation of having `static inline` functions inside header files. From what I read online, not using the `static` keyword causes a multiple definition error and that is the reason for not just defining the function as just `inline`.

However, does this mean that this function is exported for other objects to use?
If yes, then why not just defining this function in the C file and export it via the header file?
If not, why putting this in the header file rather than just having it inside the C file?

Is there a reason behind this coding style? What am I missing?

One such example can be found in the git codebase inside `hashmap.h`:

```
/*
 * Converts a cryptographic hash (e.g. SHA-1) into an int-sized hash code
 * for use in hash tables. Cryptographic hashes are supposed to have
 * uniform distribution, so in contrast to `memhash()`, this just copies
 * the first `sizeof(int)` bytes without shuffling any bits. Note that
 * the results will be different on big-endian and little-endian
 * platforms, so they should not be stored or transferred over the net.
 */
static inline unsigned int sha1hash(const unsigned char *sha1)
{
    /*
     * Equivalent to 'return *(unsigned int *)sha1;', but safe on
     * platforms that don't support unaligned reads.
     */
    unsigned int hash;
    memcpy(&hash, sha1, sizeof(hash));
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: For your reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: By "exported" do you mean "external"?  Do you perhaps more specifically mean "declared with an `extern` storage-class specifier"?

Comment: In any case, do be aware that there are already *many* questions (with answers) about C inline functions here on SO.  Are you sure that yours is meaningfully distinct?

Comment: By "exported" i mean a function that can be used by another object file. They could be functions defined in a C file and declared in a header file, and not necessarily use "extern" keyword. I have made an edit. I did see some questions about "static inline" but they did not seem to answer my question. My question is an attempt at understanding why the above code snippet is in a header file as opposed to a C file. I believe I have seen similar code inside linux kernel code as well.

Comment: Note that there is a huge difference between defining plain `static` functions in header files (quite possibly a mistake) and `static inline` functions (probably a good idea if the functions are inline-able).  If the function is too big or complex to be made inline, then you end up with a copy of the function in each object file (and you get warnings if the function is not used, whereas you don't with inline functions).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A `static inline` function is, in practice, *likely* (but not certain) to be [inlined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) by some good optimizing compiler (e.g. by [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) when it is given `-O2`) at most of its call sites.

It is defined in a header file, because it then could be inlined at most call sites (perhaps all of them). If it was just *declared* (and simply "exported") the inlining is unlikely to happen (except if you compile *and link* with [link-time optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization), a.k.a. LTO, also, e.g. compile and link with `gcc -flto -O2`, and that increases *a lot* the build time).

In practice, the compiler needs to know the body of a function to be able to inline it. So a suitable place is to define it in some common header file (otherwise, it could be inlined only in the same translation unit defining it, unless you enable LTO), so that every translation unit would know the body of that inlinable function.

It is declared `static` to avoid multiple definitions (at link time) in case the compiler did not inline it (e.g. when you use its address).

In practice, in C99 or C11 code (except with LTO, which I rarely use), I would always put the short functions I want to be inlined as `static inline` definitions in common header files.

Be sure to understand how and when the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) works. Notice that you could in principle (but it would be very bad practice and disgusting style) avoid defining some `static inline` function in a common header file and instead copy and paste its identical definition in multiple `.c` files.
(However, that might make sense for *generated* `.c` files, e.g. if you design a [compiler emitting C code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065)).

FYI [LTO](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO.html) is practically implemented by recent GCC compilers by embedding some internal compiler representation (some [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html)) inside object files, and redoing some "compilation" step - [using the `lto1` frontend](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO-Overview.html) - at "link" time. In practice, the entire program is almost compiled "twice".

<sup>(actually, I always wondered why the C standardization committee did not decide instead that all explicitly `inline` functions are static)</sup>

Comment: Probably it's worth mentioning the difference with C++'s `inline` wrt the `static` thing (spoiler: I keep forgetting about the details, so I would be extremely grateful to anyone giving a good summary).

Comment: Nice explanation. That is the practice to put a function definition in a header file.