# static inline function in C++ headers

Tags: c++

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47819719/static-inline-functions-in-a-header-file) answer about `static inline` functions in C headers, but I'm curious why would anyone add `static inline` functions in C++ headers.

Isn't `inline` enough to handle eventual linker errors when the compiler doesn't `inline` the function?

Does `static` do any harm in this case, like generating a definition in each cpp file that `include`s that header?

Comment: This is about variables, but since linkage is really about names the answer is the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58101044/is-there-any-sense-to-declare-static-global-variable-as-inline

Comment: [Should one never use static inline function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876930/should-one-never-use-static-inline-function)

Comment: note that the question you've linked to is for `c`, the rules in `c++` are different

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes, I wrote this in the question and I want to learn about the C++ rules